# aws lambda and static initalizer block

Tags: java, aws-lambda

Am new to AWS lambda developing a lambda function using java.
Am using spring in aws for DI(Dependency Injection) and i configured my lambda function with aws-api gateway. 
while Initial Request i configured spring application context in static block because static block codes gets executed while loading the class in to main memory and the class will be loaded only once in a JVM. here is my code below:-

```
System.out.println(System.getenv(PROFIES_TYPE));
springContainer = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfiguration.class);  
springContainer.getEnvironment().addActiveProfile(System.getenv(PROFIES_TYPE));
routingService = springContainer.getBean(RequestRoutingService.class);
```

this is my code which i written in static block where i can see the spring initilaizing logs twice in my aws cloud watch.
Due to spring initialization twice first request  to my aws lambda function fails because of aws api gateway timeout....

Comment: and your question is what?

Comment: Note that it is **not** a good idea to write a lambda behind an api gateway in java, the jvm overhead is too large, even more so when starting up a spring context, etc.

Comment: and my question is why static initializer block is executed twice in a same container..

Comment: are you sure it is run twice in the same container? maybe two instances of the lambda are booted up simultaneously.

Comment: without using api gateway how trigger my lambda function using EndPoint's(i know there are multiple events to trigger lambda function but my wish is the lambda function should be executed for specific http uri).

Comment: For Your Information this log is taken from same container which i took from cloud watch:-

Comment: I think you can try to explore [Spring Cloud Function](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/) by Spring, It allows us to use the Spring DI container too.<br/>
Spring Cloud Function is a project under the Spring Umbrella. It is not easy to cover the essential code. What I did was merely a pointer for the others to explore the feasibility of the library/project to resolve the problem. Here is a sample [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/run-code-with-spring-cloud-function-on-aws-lambda) that you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a problem that's created because of using spring in lambda and has nothing to do with Api Gateway. I faced the same issue with just the lambda function and I still haven't been able to figure out why it's happening. But here is the workaround that I followed to fix this issue.

1. Use a static method to initialise the spring context only during the first invocation and return the initialised context for the subsequent requests.
2. Whenever you want to read a bean, call this method to get the context and use that to create the bean you need.

   ```
   public class LambdaHandler {
       private static ApplicationContext springContext; 

       private static ApplicationContext getSpringContext() {
           if (springContext == null) {
               //initialise the spring context    
           }
           return springContext;
       }

       public void handler() {
           Foo bean = getSpringContext().getBean(Foo.class)
       }
   }
   ```